# bcmod find another variable

Tags: php, math, cryptography

I'm stacked at math question with php!

Let's say we have:

```
$first = "3707682248186045564102137590742467172304310498516787723642221858460240158712832";
$second = "23846232839228381";
$result = bcmod($first,$second);

echo $result;
// $result = 3433268;
```

How to calculate the **$first** variable (if we dont know it) if only we have **$result** and the **$second** value ?

Actually not exact value but should be close to it, so when doing

```
bcmod($first, $second);
```

it will give the $result value equal to **3433268**

Yes,

```
bcmod('3433268',$second);
```

also gives 3433268!

I appreciate all your help, thank you guys!

Comment: So you're taking the remainder of `a/b` as `c` and expecting to find `a` given only `b` and `c`? That's gonna be tough.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @rynah Yes, exactly, but `a` could be close value, not the exact one.

Comment: @user1937198 this is for cryptography purposes!

Comment: @alexvolkow: In case you're trying to break RSA or something, the impossibility of this is one reason why that type of thing is secure :)

Comment: @rynah but some how, some one did that, I'll post an answer for that if I'll find it! I'm not going to brake RSA or someting :)

Comment: Well, the infinity of integers `nb + c` satisfies that. But good luck!

Comment: For some reason this strikes me as a math question slightly disguised as a programming question :)

Answer (score 5):

Any number of numbers could have given that result. Recovering a number from its remainder when divided by something is impossible.

Comment: Not impossible, just not distinct. E.g. `$first = $second + $result;`  or just `$first = $result;` :)

Comment: @hakre: Recovering *a* number :D

Comment: @hakre: `for($i = 0; true; $i++) { if($i === 3433268) { /* Found it! */ } }`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is this: ... the mod function is not bijective ... in other words, there is no inverse function ...

let's say we calculate 10 mod 7 we get 3 ... (10 is congruent to 3 mod 7)
if we calculate 17 mod 7 we also get 3 ... (17 is also congruent to 3 mod 7)
24 mod 7 ... 3

so ... if i give you the 3 and the 7 ... and tell you the operation was "mod" ... which number do i want to hear from you?  ... 10? ... 17? ... 24?

all those numbers belong the the same remainder class ... but over the body of real numbers, every remainder class has an infinite amount of members ... therefore, if you want to reverse "mod 7", there is an infinite amount of possible functions which are candidates for the inverse of the operation you want to reverse ... but you have no information which one will be the right one ...

by reducing a number to it's remainder class (the mod function does just this), information is lost ... there is no way of getting that information back ...